# What to do if while answering a question you have a doubt that might require a new question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Assume, as the title suggest, I'm answering to a question and my solution gets the point. Suppose now that, before posting the answer, I change some parameters in my code getting a surprising result that could lead to a new question.

What to do in this case?

- Solution 1: answer anyway pointed out that if some parameters change the result could be different.
- Solution 2: answer, ask your question and then edit your answer inserting a link to the question.
- Solution 3: not insert at all the answer, but simply ask the question.

Do you see other alternatives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this depends a lot on the actual case, and how much the answer to the related question would affect your answer to the original question.

- If your answer truly answers the original question, then solution 2 seems the best.
- If your answer really depends on the answer to the related question, then it might be better to ask your question before answering the original question. Depending on what the related question is, it can sometimes be asked in chat, in which case you might be able to answer the original question directly.